# Polymorphic assosciation question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphism

In my Rails app I have models that look something like this:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

What I'm having problem with now is finding all comments under a specific blog. Can anyone see a solution to this?

Best regards,
Erik

Comment: How are you trying to find the comments? Can you post that code for us? If you are getting error messages in the console, what are the error messages?

Comment: I can't get why do you want use polymorphic associations ?

Comment: Hello!

I'm using a polymorphic assosciation because in the future I want to allow commenting on other objects than posts…

Answer (score 0):

Hi Firstly connections

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
  has_many :comments, :as=>:commentable #Post.first.comments or Blog.posts.first.comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

get all comments

```
comments=[]
Blog.first.posts.each do |post|
  comments = comments | post.comments
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about this solution. The problem though is that it'd require me to first get all posts and then loop through them all. I'd rather find a method where I can get them through SQL…